# How to compile a single .c file?

Tags: ffmpeg

Is it possible to compile a single .c file? i'm trying to modify vf_eq.c , but on ubuntu i can't get c++ to recognize the header files, if i type

```
gcc -Ihome/amadeok/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavfilter -Ihome/amadeok/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavutil  vf_eq.c
```

i get the libavfilter/internal.h: No such file or directory

if i remove libavfilter from vf_eq.c and leave only #include "internal.h" , it works. is there any way to compile only this file?

any help?

Comment: Sure it’s possible, that’s what the regular build process does. However, what’s the ultimate goal here?

Comment: Hi thanks for reply. i'm trying to combine the eq filter with the photosensitivity filter. essentially, i want to trigger the eq only when the photosensitivity filter is active. So in windows i can use visual studio to compile the -c file because the include system it has allows me to do it, but on ubuntu i haven't found a way to do it. what i need is a fast way to know if the .c file i'm working on at least doesn't have big syntax errors ect

Comment: Just `-Ihome/amadeok/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/`?